# Фокус на View при касании экрана в Android

Tags: java, android, прокрутка, view, scrollview

Подскажите, насколько я понимаю для передачи фокуса необходимо кликнуть по `View`. А как сделать так, что бы фокус переключался с одного вью на другое при движении пальца по экрану. Например, мне нужно что бы фокус передался `ScrollView` при движении по нему, а не при клике.

Comment: Пробовали вешать слушатель `Touch` на `ScrollView` и по событию `ACTION_MOVE` вызывать `requestFocus`?

Comment: да, пробовал, но дело в том, что при таком решении скрол не работает и его както нужно прокручивать программно

Answer (score 3):

1. Положите `View` поверх вашего `ScrollView` на весь экран (ну, или на всю поверхность, где нужно обрабатывать скролл.)
2. Установите этому `View` `onTouchListener`.
3. Передавайте тач-ивенты в `ScrollView`, когда это нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, простите, я новичек, не совсем понял по поводу пункта 1. Что значит поверх по ложить вью? произвольное вью какоето?

Comment: Когда я наложил View по верху моего скролла оно перехватывает только onTouch, а если наоборот скролл поверх View, то скролится но не работает onTouch :((((